# Ho to get an asp.net hosted service to run automatically on IIS 10?

Tags: asp.net, iis-10, ihostedservice

I'm having trouble with getting my hosted service to run automatically (without a user initiating a request) on IIS 10.

This is an asp.net app, .NET 7 with a React front-end. It's running Signal R and a hosted service.

I have set the start mode to "AlwaysRunning" on the Application Pool. I then set the value of Process Model.Identity to the our windows service user account. The site is configured to run with Windows Authentication and the service user has full privileges on the site folder. A user still has to hit the site's UI in order for the service to start.

Update: Thanks for the help, folks. I did set the idle timeout to 0 and the Application Initialization feature is installed. I don't think the preload option is an option in IIS 10. The service will still not automatically run.

Comment: Hey - take a read here.  I suspect you'll need a combination of "AlwaysRunning" on the application pool, preload enable = True on the web site/app, and possibly also even Idle Timeout = 0 on the application pool, to ultimately achieve what you're after.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfe80866-266a-40a2-8a1b-f69fd0b47dca/idletimeout-vs-startmode?forum=iissecurity

Comment: You are supposed to split the application into a web app on IIS to host just the SignalR hub, and a separate Windows service app, or host everything inside a Windows service app (not a web app on IIS). If you insist going on with a web app deployment, use IIS Application Initialization module, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-7.0#application-initialization-module-and-idle-timeout

Answer (score 0):

You need also to set the site to preloadEnabled=true and install the Application Initialization feature to the Windows installation as per the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization#TOC301259895).